# Adding to an iterable linked set?

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator

I am having a lot of difficulty in a recent project for my class where we have to implement generics, interfaces, iterators, and abstract data types all for the first time at once. Basically we need to create an iterable, generic linked list, and make it function like a set would, but I am struggling trying to just add a new node to the list. How would I add a node to a linked list with an iterator, when I can't access the LinkedNode fields, and the only methods in the iterator class are remove() hasNext() and Next()? LinkedNode's only public methods are getting its data and getting its link, no modifiers. Also, since its a set, I can only add elements which aren't already in the set.
This is the code I have come up with:

```
public Set<E> adjoin(E e) {
    LinkedSet<E> newSet = new LinkedSet<E>(head);
    LinkedNode<E> newNode = new LinkedNode<E>(e,head);

    for (E i : this) {
        if (i.equals(e)) {
            return this;
        }
    }

    return newSet;
}
```

This is all within the LinkedSet class, using a private constructor to make another LinkedSet to return

Comment: The iterator interface doesn't have an add method, and iterators usually don't react well if the underlying collection is modified.  It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want to over-explain it. Basically in this method we need to use a private constructor to copy the old linked list to a new one, adding the node in the parameter to the copy, but only if its not in the old one already. I tried to make it so that the method iterated through the original to check if it had the same data being inputted, and return an identical copy if the value was already in the old linked list.

Comment: I think you've said it yourself, If the only methods on the Iterator interface are boolean hasNext(), E next(), and void remove(), there is no way to add a new element to the underlying list using only the Iterator. However java.util.LinkedList does have a void add(E e) method, as well as a boolean contains(E e) method. 
It seems like your add() method could simply call the contains method, return immediately if contains() returns true.

It's useful to notice that his class doesn't expose a Node class, Nodes are an implementation detail.